# Sponge-thing that makes buttons pop back out is torn, any fix?

Tags: button

I'm not sure if this question is fit for this forum. This is my problem, I have a USB game controller (generic) and the spongy thing that's supposed to make the buttons pop back out is slightly torn. This, I believe is what's causing one of the buttons on my controller to get stuck for a few seconds before popping out again as opposed to the other 3. I included an image of what I'm talking about below.

[image: top view]

[image: bottom view]

The black parts are those that touch the electronics on the controller. So I wanna know, how do I fix this by, say, using glue of some sort?

Comment: Why the downvote? Is this *not* electronics-related? If so, where can I ask this question?

Comment: Was it really necessary to post 5 MPixel images for this? Next time please resize them; most browsers will show them 630 pixels wide, which gives more than enough information about the part.

Comment: Ahh okay, I thought the site automatically resizes the images to fit.

Comment: What kind of questions can I ask here?

- a specific electronics design problem
- the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces
- a communication scheme
- the writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications

This is not the site for:
- a shopping or buying recommendation
- consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart phones, except when designing these products or modifying their electronics for other uses
- programming software for a PC

Comment: just explaining why someone would down vote. To your problem, your best bet is either searching for a replacement part or buying a new controller. Once the plastic is torn it's pretty much stuffed.

Comment: Okay @geometrikal, can you post that as an answer so I can officially set it as one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the plastic is torn it is pretty much stuffed, so best thing is to search out a new part or buy a new controller.

Source: Flogging my AMIGA 500 joysticks to bits and trying to fix them, they used these kind of pads.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is possible to purchase replacement parts for these silicon conductive switch pads. You are more likely to be able to find replacement parts for very high distribution products than for generic and unknown products.

You may want to investigate using a replacement part from another type of controller to see if it would fit. Here is a vendor that has replacement pad for a [Nintendo DS Lite](http://www.miniinthebox.com/replacement-conductive-pad-buttons-for-nintendo-ds-lite-3-piece-set-_p78321.html) that look very similar to your part. The price is listed as very low. It may just be worth a try.

[image]